# Not in scope: data constructor ‘PayToPubKey’ - Fixing the Week 1 Pioneers Exercise

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

So in week 3 of the Plutus Pioneers program, the Plutus build changed which meant code in weeks 1 and 2 would no longer work. From what I can find, no one has published an updated set of code for weeks 1 and 2 that work with the latest build. I had a go [myself](https://github.com/BadrulAlom/learningplutus/blob/main/wk01/EnglishAuction.hs) and made some progress but I'm stumped by these two errors:

```
Compilation Error, Line 169, Column 13 (jump)
 error:
    Not in scope: data constructor ‘PayToPubKey’
    |
169 |             PayToPubKey   -> traceError "wrong output type"
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^
Compilation Error, Line 170, Column 13 (jump)
 error:
    Not in scope: data constructor ‘PayToScript’
```

Any suggestions on how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

The updated code for this looks like this:

```
ownOutput   :: TxOut
outputDatum :: AuctionDatum
(ownOutput, outputDatum) = case getContinuingOutputs ctx of
    [o] -> case txOutDatumHash o of
        Nothing   -> traceError "wrong output type"
        Just h -> case findDatum h info of
            Nothing        -> traceError "datum not found"
            Just (Datum d) ->  case PlutusTx.fromData d of
                Just ad' -> (o, ad')
                Nothing  -> traceError "error decoding data"
    _   -> traceError "expected exactly one continuing output"
```

The TxOutInfo type has now been replaced with TxOut which combines the data for a public key address and a script address. A public key address will not have a Datum, hence the Maybe.

```
data TxOut = TxOut {
  txOutAddress   :: Address,
  txOutValue     :: Value,
  txOutDatumHash :: Maybe DatumHash
}
```

The updated code for week 1 is now available in iteration 2 of the program, currently in the [main branch of the Plutus Pioneer Program repo](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program).